# jQuery table filter slow

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a very large table of data and I want to filter it by letter.  I have buttons A-Z and 1 (for numeric) at the top of the page.  When the user clicks a button, it should only show the rows that start with that letter (or a number if they click '1').

It works, but it is a bit slow to load since the table has thousands of rows.  Is there a more efficient way of doing this that will help the page load faster?

```js
// Limit to rows whose first cell's text starts with a given letter
$(".alphaList li button").click(function() {
  var value = $(this).text().toUpperCase();
  var cellText = '';
  var firstChar = '';

  if (isNumeric($(this).text())) {
    // For 0-9
    $("#alphaTable tr:not(#alphaTableHeader)").filter(function() {
      cellText = $(this).find('td:first-child').text().toUpperCase().trim()
      firstChar = cellText.substring(0, 1)

      $(this).toggle(isNumeric(firstChar))
    });
  } else {
    // For letters
    $("#alphaTable tr:not(#alphaTableHeader)").filter(function() {
      cellText = $(this).find('td:first-child').text().toUpperCase().trim()
      firstChar = cellText.substring(0, 1)

      $(this).toggle(firstChar == value)

    });
  }
});
```

```html
<table id="alphaTable">
  <thead>
    <tr id="alphaTableHeader">
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>123</td>
      <td>234</td>
      <td>ABC</td>
      <td>ABBC</td>
      <td>BCD</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You're using `.filter` as `.each` - ie looping every element and not using the return value.   For efficient page updates, keep DOM changes to a minimum - a *single* call to `.hide()` and a *single* call to `.show()` - remove your `.toggle` from inside the loop and .hide() all then .show() on the result of `filter` (outside of the `.filter()` loop with the filter returning values to show)

Comment: So your criteria is the first character of the first TD in a given TR? If that matches, then show the row, otherwise hide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could preemptively assign a special class and then reference it in your filter function...

```js
// after the data is loaded...
$("#alphaTable tbody tr").each(function(i, o) {
  let letter = $(o).find('td').eq(0).text().slice(0, 1)
  $(this).addClass(`row_${letter.toUpperCase()}`);
})

// Limit to rows whose first cell's text starts with a given letter
$("#filters button").click(function() {
  let letter = $(this).text().toUpperCase() ;
  if (letter == 'RESET') return $("#alphaTable tbody tr").show();
  $("#alphaTable tbody tr").hide();
  $(`tr.row_${letter}`).show();
})
```

```css
#alphaTable tbody tr,
tr[class^="row_"]{
  display:none;
}

#alphaTable tbody tr.row_A{
  display: table-row;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='filters'>
  <button>1</button><button>A</button><button>Reset</button>
</div>
<table id="alphaTable">
  <thead>
    <tr id="alphaTableHeader">
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>123</td><td>234</td><td>ABC</td><td>ABBC</td><td>BCD</td></tr>   
    <tr><td>A123</td><td>234</td><td>ABC</td><td>ABBC</td><td>BCD</td></tr> 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks.  Preemptively assigning the class works great - it trimmed off a couple of seconds.  I can still see all the rows for a second or two when the page loads (before it hides all but the "A" rows).  I'm assuming this is because of the large number of rows and that the JavaScript hasn't run yet.

Comment: You could easily set a css rule for page initialization, I added it to the answer

Comment: Ah, yes of course.  I was too busy thinking about the Javascript, I wasn't thinking about the CSS to solve this part.  Thanks for your help.